# Insert into partitioned table taking very long time

Tags: mysql, partitioning, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I have table structure like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dnddata` (
  `numbers` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `opstype` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numbers`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (numbers)
PARTITIONS 20 */;
```

When I inserting data into this table taking long time.

Taking 50 min to insert 3 million records.

I have used `load data` and `insert into dnddata SELECT * from another_myisamtable`.

Both methods are taking nearly equal time.

Same table without partition taking less than 2 min.

I have to insert data of 50 million records.

Please suggest which is the best way to insert this many records.

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM? Is innodb not an option?

Comment: @Anthony: This post is from 2012, but was recently edited.  Your comment on this question might be too late.

Comment: Yeah, I realized about 20.12 seconds too late

Answer (score 3):

The funny thing about partitioned tables is that when you try and `INSERT` into just one partition, you have to go and lock down (or at least "pay the lock a visit") all partitions. So - more partitions == more locks.

You can read more about it in [Giuseppe Maxia's blog](http://datacharmer.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/two-quick-performance-tips-with-mysql.html).

Although said post discusses the `INSERT` of single rows, the same problem applies to multiple rows as well.

Since you are using MyISAM, actual locks are taken. You may choose to try the same with an InnoDB table of the same format.

Comment: Thanks shlomi, locking is not a problem for us. we insert the records while server is idle. my requirement is insert in less time..

Comment: I understand. Nevertheless this locking takes time in itself, regardless of possible contention.